# Can I use custom product feature values for navigation in prestashop?

Tags: prestashop-1.6, layered-navigation

Hello I am trying to create some filters in Prestashop, I' ve made all the steps necessary I think, but the layered navigation block shows only the product features that have pre-defined values and doesn't seem to use the features based on custom values at all. Is this standard behavior or am  I missing something?

Thnx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know about newest version, but yes, its kind of "bug" that module dont use custom values.

Check this tutorial! http://blog.belvg.com/custom-features-in-prestashop-blocklayered-module.html

I tried it by myself and it works. Good luck.